# Do the words "angst" and "anxiety" share a common root?

Tags: english, etymology, indo-european, germanic-languages, romance-languages

The English word *angst,* taken from German *Angst,* seems to ultimately originate from Proto-Germanic **angustiz*. This word has descendants in many Germanic languages, including, but not limited to, Danish, Norwegian, Swedish, German and Dutch. The English word *anger* is also related to this group.

The English word *anxiety* has a similar meaning and seems to derive from Latin *anxietās*. This word has cognates all over the Romance languages, including, but not limited to, French, Italian, Spanish and Portuguese.

These two groups of cognates mean similar things. If we go even further back, is there a link between the two groups, for example in Proto Indo European?

I would prefer if answers included a source.

Comment: By the way, [*angst*](http://www.oxfordlearnersdictionaries.com/definition/american_english/angst?q=angst) is not an inherited word in English. It was borrowed from German *Angst* "fear."

Comment: @sumelic Does that mean I made a mistake in the question, or are you just providing additional information?

Comment: From the way you phrased the question, I wasn't sure if you knew. Generally, in historical linguistics  the term "cognate" only refers to words that have a continuous line of transmission from a common ancestor. By this definition, English "angst" does not have any cognates, as it is a loanword. See this question for more explanation: [Is a loanword also a cognate or are the two terms mutually exclusive?](http://linguistics.stackexchange.com/questions/4667/is-a-loanword-also-a-cognate-or-are-the-two-terms-mutually-exclusive)

Comment: @sumelic I see. No, I totally didn't know that. Could you edit my question to remove the inaccuracy?

Comment: @sumelic *Anguish* as cognate was taken from Wiktionary. Etymology Online also relates *anguish* to *anger*.

Comment: "Anguish" is ultimately related, but it is not Germanic. I wasn't sure where to put it. It comes from French *angoisse* from Latin *angustia.*

Comment: @sumelic Oh, I see. In that sense, it is probably more related to the second group. Maybe better to just leave it out.

Comment: That's what I was thinking :)

Comment: @sumelic: That is not how I have ever seen the word *cognate* used, in such a narrow sense! To me, sharing a common root is synonymous with being cognate. Nor, frankly, has that answer convinced me to use it differently from now on. I've never seen its mening limited such that borrowing between languages should destroy cognation. And there is considerable dissent among the answers to and comments on that question.

Comment: I have the same terminological intuitions as @Cerberus.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

Yes, Germanic *angst* and Latin *anxiety* are are derived from the same Proto-Indo-European root, which was something like **h₂enǵʰ-* "constrict, narrow".

Philippa (2003-2009) confirm that they are cognates: under *[angst](http://www.etymologiebank.nl/trefwoord/angst1)* they say, "see *eng*"; under *[eng](http://www.etymologiebank.nl/trefwoord/eng1)* they say that the word is related to Latin *ango* and they give the Proto-Indo-European root as above. Also related is *angina*, from Greek.

De Vaan (2008) says *anxius* is derived from *ango* as expected, and mentions the same root as Philippa.

Idle speculation: the root may be onomatopoeic, because an emphatic sound /ŋ/ resembles the sound one makes when one's throat is blocked or constricted.

Comment: Re your idle speculation, the Hebrew root for "choke, suffocate" is *ħ-n-q* (coincidence? onomatopoeia? Nostratic cognate?).

Comment: @TKR: Ah, very interesting! Let's call it a Nostratic onomatopoeia that need not have been.

Comment: @TKR I suggest you start a paper on all of this right away. It will be the start of hte Cerberus-TKR theorem.

Comment: @Fiksdal: It shall be the Fiksdal-TKT-Cerberus theorem!

Comment: LOL, I'm flattered that you're including me